# Calibrating DTMs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I downloaded some raw elevation DTMs from QGIS and need to calibrate them to a known height, they are about 10m off. I have a point that I know the elevation to be 174.34m ASL.

I had done the calibration in Drone Deploy itself, but the downloaded file did not reflect that.

Can this be done in QGIS? Say click on a point and tell it what that altitude is and in turn calibrate the whole DTM?

Comment: Is the offset constant for the whole raster? Maybe raster calculator is an option: add/subtract a constant from your raster.

Comment: You can use the raster calculator capabilities in QGIS to add or subtract a values from a raster but your problem is a vertical datum issue.  Better to figure out 1. Which sea level (MHHW, MSL, MLLW) is your point referencing, 2. What vertical datum is Drone Deploy returning (WGS 84 ellipsoid, height above take-off), 3. What vertical datum is your downloaded surface model referencing before you start arbitrarily adding or subtracting values from surfaces.  Arbitrarily adding or subtracting values from your surfaces is just going to add error. Use Vdatum (or ArcPro) to convert datums.